# Mathtools package cramped command

Tags: packages, tex-core, mathtools

Within the `mathtools` package, `\cramped` is defined as follows.

```
\providecommand*\cramped[1][\@empty]{
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \expandafter \mathpalette \expandafter \MT_cramped_internal:Nn
  \else
    \expandafter \MT_cramped_internal:Nn \expandafter #1
  \fi
}
\def\MT_cramped_internal:Nn #1#2{
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\nulldelimiterspace=\z@\radical\z@{#2}$}
    \ifx#1\displaystyle
      \dimen@=\fontdimen8\textfont3
      \advance\dimen@ .25\fontdimen5\textfont2
    \else
      \dimen@=1.25\fontdimen8
      \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont
      \else
        \ifx#1\scriptstyle
          \scriptfont
        \else
          \scriptscriptfont
        \fi
      \fi
      3
    \fi
    \advance\dimen@-\ht\z@ \ht\z@=-\dimen@
    \box\z@
}
```

**Q1** After reading Appendix G of *The TeXbook* (Rule 18), why wouldn't the package simply do the following (locally within the math environment)?

```
\fontdimen13\textfont2=\fontdimen15\textfont2
\fontdimen14\textfont2=\fontdimen15\textfont2
\fontdimen13\scriptfont2=\fontdimen15\scriptfont2
\fontdimen14\scriptfont2=\fontdimen15\scriptfont2
\fontdimen13\scriptscriptfont2=\fontdimen15\scriptscriptfont2
\fontdimen14\scriptscriptfont2=\fontdimen15\scriptscriptfont2
```

**Q2** I omit here the code to make it local because I'm not sure how to do it but surely it's doable(?) Does anyone know how to do it locally?

Comment: I think the issue is precisely with the "locally". `\fontdimen` assignments are always global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the TeXbook, page 277:

> In all of the following cases, the presence or absence of `\global` as a prefix has no effect.
>
> ⟨global assignment⟩ → ⟨font assignment⟩
>     | ⟨hyphenation assignment⟩
>     | ⟨box size assignment⟩
>     | ⟨interaction mode assignment⟩
>     | ⟨intimate assignment⟩
> ⟨font assignment⟩ → `\fontdimen`⟨number⟩⟨font⟩⟨equals⟩⟨dimen⟩
>     | `\hyphenchar`⟨font⟩⟨equals⟩⟨number⟩
>     | `\skewchar`⟨font⟩⟨equals⟩⟨number⟩
> ⟨hyphenation assignment⟩ → `\hyphenation`⟨general text⟩
>     | `\patterns`⟨general text⟩
> ⟨box size assignment⟩ → ⟨box dimension⟩⟨8-bit number⟩⟨equals⟩⟨dimen⟩
> ⟨interaction mode assignment⟩ → `\errorstopmode` | `\scrollmode`
>     | `\nonstopmode` | `\batchmode`
> ⟨intimate assignment⟩ → ⟨special integer⟩⟨equals⟩⟨number⟩
>     | ⟨special dimen⟩⟨equals⟩⟨dimen⟩

The case you're interested in is

> ⟨font assignment⟩ → `\fontdimen`⟨number⟩⟨font⟩⟨equals⟩⟨dimen⟩

and you see that such assignment is global independently of adding `\global` in front of `\fontdimen`.

You might think to do the setting and undo it after processing, but this doesn't work, because the `\fontdimen` parameter are only examined when math mode ends and the math list is converted to a horizontal list. The only way would be to add a boxing level, starting math mode inside it (don't forget to use `\mathchoice`), doing the setting of the parameters, process the subformula, end math mode, undo the settings and finish the box.